# Group Chat XMPP with Google App Engine

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, xmpp

Google App Engine has a great XMPP service built in. One of the few limitations it has is that it doesn't support receiving messages from a group chat. That's the one thing I want to do with it. :(
Can I run a 3rd party XMPP/Jabber server on App Engine that supports group chat?
If so, which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. App Engine apps can only directly handle HTTP requests - you can't run arbitrary servers on App Engine.